# How can my Protocol oriented to specify ViewModel?

Tags: swift, mvvm, protocols

I have a problem from Protocol oriented ViewModels.
**I have two very similar pages**,so i made a baseController and baseViewModel to put shared properties and methods. And made two other controllers and viewModels for two pages.
And I made a protocol to define the properties and methods.

My baseController has `var viewModel: BaseViewModelProtocol` .
But my other two controller cannot use the properties and methods from their viewModel, it's says

> Value of type 'BaseViewModelProtocol?' has no member ''

ViewModel1 is for Controller1, ViewModel2 is for Controller2, here is my example

```swift
protocol BaseViewModelProtocol {
    var name: String { get }
    func reset()
} 

class BaseViewModel: BaseViewModelProtocol {
    func reset() { }
}

class ViewModel1: BaseViewModel {
    var score: Int = 0
    func someMethods() {}
}

class ViewModel2: BaseViewModel {
    var money: Int = 1000 
    func something() {
        print("something")
    }
}


class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var viewModel: BaseViewModelProtocol?

    init(viewModel: BaseViewModelProtocol) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

}

class ViewController1: BaseViewController {
    
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(viewModel?.score)     //it is error!!!!
    }
}
```

When i init the Controller, i Cannot use any properties and methods from ViewModel2, and the same like controller1.

```swift
class ViewController2: BaseOrderViewController {
     
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewModel?.something().  //it is error!!!!
    }

}
```

how to my protocol oriented viewModel?

Comment: Regarding the error in `ViewController1`. Why do you expect it to even have the var `score`? `ViewModel1` defines it, but neither `BaseViewModelProtocol` nor `BaseViewController` do. Better start looking into some tutorials how this stuff works. These implementation or your expectations to it are wrong.

Comment: @iRogerz You are doing some terrific implementation. Please understand what does protocol oriented programing mean and then try to understand how you can implement it with ViewModel concept

Comment: OK thanks for your suggest, I will go to learn POP

Answer (score 1):

After reading your post I feel like there is too many things that should be addressed here.

You are trying to ask something before understanding important characteristics of the Object Oriented Programmation paradigm. I recommend you to try and search information about class abstraction, composition vs inheritance and specificaly how to use the protocols in Swift.

Maybe you could start with https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-create-an-abstract-class-in-swift.

---

Even so, i am going to try to point out some issues in your code.

- Seems like you tried to "hide" your source code by changing your classes and properties' names. The way it's done makes it harder to read, understand and introduces mistakes.
- Inheriting from another class:

  ```
   class ViewModel1: BaseViewModel
  ```

  it's not the same as inheriting from a protocol:

  ```
   class BaseViewModel: BaseViewModelProtocol
  ```

  while the first one provides you a default implementation of a method that can be overrided, the second, doesn't. So it is mandatory to provide the implementation of the method in every class that inherits the protocol.
- Note that the BaseViewController has a property with type BaseViewModelProtocol. That protocol doesn't have a method called "something" neither can inherit that function from another. It's within reason that the compiler shows the error.
- If you want to use "something" from a Class that inherits BaseViewController, you have many ways. You could change the type of the viewModel in the BaseViewController to BaseViewModel after adding there an implementation of "something". You could also add the function to the protocol and make sure that it's implemented in all of the classes which inherit the protocol...

I hope I have helped you.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have solve my problem. I use associatedtype in my protocol like `associatedtype VM = Self` and generic 
 `BaseOrderViewController<T: OrderBaseViewModelProtocol>` . `OrderOddViewController: BaseOrderViewController<OrderOddViewModel>`  to oriented my ViewModel